# How do I call custom pages from Site Assets?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, custom, video

We produce videos (mp4) in Camtasia that contain interactive linking, quizzes, and other material specific to the video.  This material is built into the video using the Camtasia 'Smart Player' and is made accessible by clicking the html page created during production.  This html page references several other files to make the magic happen (js, css, html, mp4, png)...

We're not having any success in getting the customized videos to render.  At this point, the embedded files produced with the .mp4 have been uploaded to the Site Pages directory and called on directly (which results in an infinite loading screen) and we have placed the embedded files created into the Site Assets library, modified the .html extensions and code behind to reflect aspx, and loaded just the .aspx file into the Site Page directly;  this results in a 404 error.

Has there been any testing done with this?  Can anyone point me into the right direction for a proper resource?  We've tried webparts, wiki pages, etc., etc.  I am the site administrator and have given myself the full control and modified permissions to allow for custom code.

What am I missing?

After following the instructions given in this video link, we still fail.

https://youtu.be/BGdgUaIl360

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging, I have found the answer.  As a couple of people have pointed out, there have been some changes to Sharepoint that made this more difficult, but not impossible.

The trick to call custom pages was to create a sub-site for the Sharepoint site, do my work within the sub-site, then call the custom page from the main site.  Here are the steps that I followed:

1. Produced external content (html, css, script, etc.)
2. Created a sub-site within the Sharepoint primary site.
3. Created a Document Library in the sub-site (I named mine 'Video Content').
4. Created a directory structure in the Video Content library
5. Renamed my html files to aspx files.
6. Modified the source code for the iframe src attribute in the primary aspx file to call the entire URL of the 'smart player' aspx file.  This included the protocol, site, structure, etc.

   https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sub-site-name/document-library/internal-structure/called-file.aspx
7. Imported my modified primary aspx file using SharePoint designer (I found the code could also be embedded once it was modified if 'Custom Code' was allowed).
8. With the new .aspx file in the Site Pages section, I was able to link that page using a Web Part from the Primary Site.

I hope this helps someone else struggling.

Answer (score 1):

Running a html/aspx file directly from SharePoint libraries in browser only works when it is an **independent** web file.

SharePoint Online does not support using a html/aspx file to call other components in the project directly from a document library or Site Assets.

You need to deploy the project as a [custom solution](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/extend-and-develop) or using [SharePoint Framework (SPFx)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part) to build a client-side web part.

If you want to play the mp4 video on SharePoint page, consider uploading the video to **Microsoft Stream**, then insert the video on modern page via [Stream webpart](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/stream/embed-video-sharepoint), as long as the mp4 video is able to play without other components in your project.

Comment: That's disappointing.  Reading over the first link it sounds as if it was possible in the classic SharePoint sites but in the new version they've removed the functionality without SPFx or something similar.  Does that mean I can change the settings from the SharePoint admin center to create all new sites in a classic and get around the new 'feature'?

Comment: To add, Microsoft Stream is an option, just not a good one for us as the .mp4 file is dumb.  All of the intelligence is built into the smart player housed in the .html files; that means all of our interaction built in will stop working.

Comment: @RunninThruLife I’m note sure if it is still available in SharePoint Online anymore, classic or modern. I didn’t have a Camtasia project to test with, so I upload a html project and try to open the index.aspx file from the folder. It refused to open the file and gave an “Something went wrong” error. Then I changed the file extension back to html, it opened in browser, but the contents were not loading since SharePoint could not identify the other components of the project. But if I open Site Assets in file explorer, the project works as normal.

Answer (score 0):

So probably a really high level response right now but you could either change the URL to Site Assets file or use iframes to display the other files. I have experience in .aspx and custom files in SharePoint but never tried embedding sorry

Comment: We have the custom pages being displayed in iframes at the moment... still no luck.  Can you clarify what you mean by 'change the URL to Site Assets'?

I'm unclear as to whether the URL in the iframe src attribute should include the protocol and the site or if it should start at the folder in the root.

1. https://mysite.sharepoint.com/SiteAssets/MyDirectory

... or ...

2. SiteAssets/MyDirectory